# How can i add default copts like '-fopenmp' for the cc_library?

Tags: c++, openmp, bazel

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html

About the copts option:

> Each string in this attribute is added in the given order to COPTS before compiling the binary target. The flags take effect only for compiling this target, not its dependencies, so be careful about header files included elsewhere. All paths should be relative to the workspace, not to the current package.

```
cc_library(
    name = 'lib1',
    srcs = glob([
        'src/*.cpp',
    ]),
    hdrs = glob([
        'include/*.h',
        'include/**/*.h',
    ]),
    copts = [ 
        '-std=c++11',
        '-fopenmp',
        '-march=native',
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "test1",
    srcs = ["tests/test1.cpp"],
    deps = [
        ":lib1",
    ],
    copts = [ 
        '-std=c++11',
        '-fopenmp',
        '-march=native',
    ],
)
```

If i remove the copts in the test1 rule, the compilation will failed. How can i  modify the lib1 rule, so that all rules depends on it can also compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every targets need `-std=c++ -fopenmp -march=native` when compiling, it is better to specify the copts in build command (`bazel build --copt="-std=c++" --copt="-fopenmp" --copt="-march=native" //src:hello`). Then you can remove the `copts` in `cc_*` rules.

Also note that if you want to use `-march=native` in one file, it is always best to ensure that all other files compile with this flag too to avoid some bugs that can be caused by compiler optimization.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to add `linkopts = ["-lgomp"]` to your `cc_binary` rule.

Comment: I guess `linkops` is a typo, I had to fix to `linkopts`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to add `--linkopt='-lgomp'` to my `.bazelrc` file.
For completeness, the `.bazelrc` is exactly: `build --cxxopt='-std=c++17' --cxxopt='-Ofast' --cxxopt='-fopenmp' --linkopt='-lgomp'`

Bazel version is `bazel 3.7.0`.

Since I cannot comment on @Cheng Ji answer, I'll just emphasize that his answer helped me a lot, but it didn't work at first by adding `linkops = ["-lgomp"]` into `cc_binary` (it complained `no such attribute 'linkops' in 'cc_binary' rule`).
Then I discovered that `linkops` was a typo, so I tried `linkopts = ["-lgomp"]` and it also worked! Thanks a lot for that!